# VMWare GhettoVCB fails consistantly

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi

I am running esxi 5.0 and just installed the GhettoVCB backup scripts.  When I run the backup it fails consistently at 26%.  Here is the debug log http://pastebin.com/Cj29Qfer  I have run this backup to an iSCSI and an NFS on a QNAP over gig ethernet and I've even tried to use the local disk and it fails at the 26% mark.  I know I have enough disk space, the read write permissions are set to where everyone has read write access....i'm at a loss right now, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
msindle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was caused due to my using of unsupported hardware for esxi 5.  I loaded vmware on supported hardware and it completed without any problems.